# How to apply a png texture over my material?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

everybody!

I making a Barbie style doll model. I've UV mapped the face part and created her eyes and lips using photoshop and saved the texture as a png.
The face has a node setup for plastic looking skin and I would like to add my texture over it.

I've found similar questions on this website but the ones I found were for older blender versions and I couldn't figure it out how to do it on Blender 2.91.

Below is my current node setup and also the texture I want to apply.

[image: Node setup]

[image: Png Texture]

Comment: You should add links to the "similar" questions to help us understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking a way to use "MIX SHADER".
check this settings:

[image]

- add a MIX shader node and as inputs 2 principled BSDF (one for the plastic look, one with the texture)
- as factor as MIX shader use the Alpha channel of your image
- fix the UV map if needed..

Suzanne is now happy:
[image]

Comment: It's exactly that, thank you! And Suzanne is looking dashing!